# Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): Connection refused, twice each 5 secs with Laravel Horizon but horizon is working

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

I'm having a lot of errors in laravel.log at the frequence of  2 errors each 4-5 seconds.

Here is the error:

```
[2020-12-09 16:37:09] production.ERROR: Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): Connection refused at /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:141)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(141): Redis->connect()
#1 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(84): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->establishConnection()
#2 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(263): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#3 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(109): tap()
#4 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(28): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->createClient()
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#6 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PhpRedisConnection.php(541): call_user_func()
#7 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PhpRedisConnection.php(272): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connections\\PhpRedisConnection->command()
#8 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Repositories/RedisSupervisorRepository.php(39): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connections\\PhpRedisConnection->zrevrangebyscore()
#9 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Repositories/RedisSupervisorRepository.php(50): Laravel\\Horizon\\Repositories\\RedisSupervisorRepository->names()
#10 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Repositories/RedisSupervisorRepository.php(99): Laravel\\Horizon\\Repositories\\RedisSupervisorRepository->all()
#11 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/MasterSupervisor.php(165): Laravel\\Horizon\\Repositories\\RedisSupervisorRepository->longestActiveTimeout()
#12 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/ListensForSignals.php(52): Laravel\\Horizon\\MasterSupervisor->terminate()
#13 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/MasterSupervisor.php(237): Laravel\\Horizon\\MasterSupervisor->processPendingSignals()
#14 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/MasterSupervisor.php(212): Laravel\\Horizon\\MasterSupervisor->loop()
#15 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Console/HorizonCommand.php(56): Laravel\\Horizon\\MasterSupervisor->monitor()
#16 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Laravel\\Horizon\\Console\\HorizonCommand->handle()
#17 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#18 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#19 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#20 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(610): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#21 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#22 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#23 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#24 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(971): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#25 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(290): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#26 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(166): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#27 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#28 /home/ubuntu/myuser/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#29 /home/ubuntu/myuser/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#30 {main}
"}
```

Here is my config:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

in my .env :

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=MyPassword
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Here is the stack:

- Horizon Version: 5.6.0
- Laravel Version: 8.17.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.3
- Redis Driver & Version: predis/phpredis 5.0.7 / 1.1.6
- Database Driver & Version: Postgres 12

What should I do to get rid of them ?

Comment: having the same problem. any fix?

Comment: Nop ! I raised an issue on github, but I were told to post here :/ If you find a solution, please let me know !

Comment: can you share me the github issue link so I can follow?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/944

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? It happened to me while testing a better database structure with laravel forge following:

2x Web server
1x Load balancer
1x Cache server
1x Db server

Answer (score -1):

You should disable Selinux or set it to permissive mode.